# How to replace only numeric values in Data frame column with value from other column

Tags: python, pandas, replace

My first question. I can not find a solution how to replace only values that are numeric ind Pandas df.

I have a data frame like below:

```
index   sposob-produkcji    rok-produkcji
0   FABRYCZNY   FABRYCZNY
1   FABRYCZNY   2010
2   FABRYCZNY   2010
3   FABRYCZNY   2009
4   FABRYCZNY   2009
... ... ...
41139   2022        FABRYCZNY
41140   2020        FABRYCZNY
41141   2019        FABRYCZNY
41142   2016        FABRYCZNY
41143   1975        FABRYCZNY
```

I want to replace all (and only) numeric values in col1 with value from col2.

I did it one by one as below and it works.

```
cars['sposob-produkcji'] = np.where(cars['sposob-produkcji']  ==  2022, cars['rok-produkcji'] , cars['sposob-produkcji']  )
```

But can't find "general" formula.
Those one don't work:

```
cars['sposob-produkcji'] = np.where(cars['sposob-produkcji'].str.isnumeric()  ==  True, cars['rok-produkcji'] , cars['sposob-produkcji']  )

cars['sposob-produkcji'] = np.where(cars['sposob-produkcji'].str.isdigit()  ==  True, cars['rok-produkcji'] , cars['sposob-produkcji']  )
```

I think that problem is with data type. Those values seems to be numeric...?

Any hints?
Thans,
Tomek

Comment: `np.where(cars['sposob-produkcji'].str.match(r'\d+'), ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here are two way to do that

stripping away the blanks and then checking if its a digit

```
df['sposob-produkcji'] = np.where(df['sposob-produkcji'].str.strip().str.isdigit(), df['rok-produkcji'], df['sposob-produkcji'] )
df
```

OR

using match as @jch suggested and assigning back to the sposob-produkcji

```
df['sposob-produkcji'] = np.where(df['sposob-produkcji'].str.match(r'\d+'), df['rok-produkcji'], df['sposob-produkcji'] )
df
```

```
    index   sposob-produkcji    rok-produkcji
0   0       FABRYCZNY   FABRYCZNY
1   1       FABRYCZNY   2010
2   2       FABRYCZNY   2010
3   3       FABRYCZNY   2009
4   4       FABRYCZNY   2009
5   41139   FABRYCZNY   FABRYCZNY
6   41140   FABRYCZNY   FABRYCZNY
7   41141   FABRYCZNY   FABRYCZNY
8   41142   FABRYCZNY   FABRYCZNY
9   41143   FABRYCZNY   FABRYCZNY
```